# How Can Spread Syntax Be Used Within Optional Chaining?

Tags: typescript

Not long ago optional chaining was introduced in TypeScript. Admittedly, it is an incredibly useful feature pushing us to write more readable code.

However, I found myself in a situation where it looks like I need to chain a spread array. Is there an easy way to do that with optional chaining?

PS. I am aware I can achieve that with `get` from lodash: `get(myObject, [...myPropsArray])`.

Comment: `where it looks like I need to chain a spread array` can you please show your code? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Elias when you look on the documentation it will be clear what he means. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get His array is a list of props to access the required value. Like `myObject[myPropsArray[0]][myPropsArray[1]]....`

Comment: Spread syntax makes it very easy to generalise - I may have an array of 2 properties but also of 10. As @MoxxiManagarm mentioned, I want to use them to access a value of unknown depth in an object.